# Sending notifications to specific user with Expo - React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

`Platform: React Native (IOS target)`

Hi,

I am trying to build a way to send push notifications ( it's basically an app simillar to any datting app where you click a user and it sends them a notification to let them know I want to connect).

The notifications are being received fine on Expo Go but I don't know how to target a specific individual? Do I need backend for this?

This is my code:

```
const ProfilesScreen: React.FC<Props> = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  const [expoPushToken, setExpoPushToken] = useState("");
  const [notification, setNotification] = useState(false);
  const [notificationRes, setNotifcationRes] = useState([]);
  const notificationListener = useRef();
  const responseListener = useRef();
  const [data, setData] = useState<any>([]);
  const [notificationsSentUids, setNotificationSentUids] = useState<any>([]);
  const [notificationsCount, setNotificationsCount] = useState<number>(0);
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState<number>(0);
  const [storageData, setStorageData] = useState({});

  async function sendPushNotification(expoPushToken) {
    const message = {
      to: expoPushToken,
      sound: "default",
      title: "My message",
      body: storageData
        ? `${storageData?.name} wants to connect with you`
        : null,
      data: { someData: "goes here" },
    };
    await fetch("https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(message),
    });
  }
  async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync() {
    let token;
    if (Device.isDevice) {
      const { status: existingStatus } =
        await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
      let finalStatus = existingStatus;
      if (existingStatus !== "granted") {
        const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
        finalStatus = status;
      }
      if (finalStatus !== "granted") {
        alert("Failed to get push token for push notification!");
        return;
      }
      token = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()).data;
      setExpoPushToken(token);
    } else {
      // alert("Must use physical device for Push Notifications");
    }
    return token;
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    registerForPushNotificationsAsync().then(token => setExpoPushToken(token));
    // This listener is fired whenever a notification is received while the app is foregrounded
    notificationListener.current =
      Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener(notification => {
        setNotification(notification);
      });

    // This listener is fired whenever a user taps on or interacts with a notification (works when app is foregrounded, backgrounded, or killed)
    responseListener.current =
      Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(response => {
        setNotifcationRes(response);
    return () => {
      Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(
        notificationListener.current
      );
      Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(responseListener.current);
    };
  }, []);
  return .... 
};
```

Comment: With the use of `expoPushToken` you're already doing this.
You might want to use a backend for security reasons tho.

Comment: thanks @Poptocrack. Don't understand how I am doing that already, from my understanding these are like general notifications, the expoPushToken seems to just to register the notification that is sent to all devices that have the same app? how do I know that when I click "Mike's user profile image" the notification is being sent to Mike and Mike only and not other users? In fact currently I receive the notification in my own device and not on "Mike's device".

Comment: Each user will have a different expoPushToken (which you get from registerForPushNotificationsAsync) You could send push token with the user infos, like user.name = Mike and user.notifToken = xxx

You should not send notifications to another user directly from the current user device tho, but it should work since you only have to call an api